# Is it possible to get push notification through enterprise provision profile (In House Enterprise)?

Tags: ios, push-notification

Is it possible to get push notification through enterprise provision profile? 
I am not releasing the app to app store, So I distribute the app using enterprise provision profile(In House Enterprise). My question is

1) Enterprise provision profile(In House Enterprise) get push notification for that app without adding the UDID ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, just like a with a normal app store app. Just register for push notification and send the received token to your APNS server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to get push notification distributed using enterprise provisioning. Just ensure that you are using the right certificate for the app.

Your device gets registered irrespective of the type of the provisioning profile.